# Cannot inherit from generic base class and specific interface using same type with generic constraint

Tags: generics, inheritance, c#-3.0, interface

Sorry about the strange title. I really have no idea how to express it any better...

I get an error on the following snippet. I use the class Dummy everywhere. Doesn't the compiler understand the constraint I've added on DummyImplBase? Is this a compiler bug as it works if I use Dummy directly instead of setting it as a constraint?

Error 1 'ConsoleApplication53.DummyImplBase' does not implement interface member 'ConsoleApplication53.IRequired.RequiredMethod()'. 'ConsoleApplication53.RequiredBase.RequiredMethod()' cannot implement 'ConsoleApplication53.IRequired.RequiredMethod()' because it does not have the matching return type of 'ConsoleApplication53.Dummy'. C:\Documents and Settings\simen\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\ConsoleApplication53\ConsoleApplication53\Program.cs 37 27 ConsoleApplication53

```
public class Dummy
{
}

public interface IRequired<T>
{
    T RequiredMethod();
}

public interface IDummyRequired : IRequired<Dummy>
{
    void OtherMethod();
}

public class RequiredBase<T> : IRequired<T>
{
    public T RequiredMethod()
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}

public abstract class DummyImplBase<T> : RequiredBase<T>, IDummyRequired
    where T: Dummy
{
    public void OtherMethod()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add this to DummyImplBase:

```
   public Dummy RequiredMethod() { return base.RequiredMethod(); }
```

EDIT: Or, if you're using C# 4.0, you could change definition of IRequired like so:

```
public interface IRequired<out T>
```

then remove IDummyRequired and you would still be able to assign derived classes to
`IRequired<Dummy>` (but not to IDummyRequired).

2nd EDIT: Your original code did not compile, because T could be Dummy or a class derived from Dummy. And the implemented Method

```
public DummyDerived RequiredMethod()
```

has not the same as signature as

```
public Dummy RequiredMethod()
```

which was declared in IDummyDerived.

Comment: This seems more like a tedious hack by hiding the original methods, and still.. This doesn't give me the advantage of generics. Then I have to do this in the derived classes as well to give the same result.

Comment: 2nd Edit: Ah, of course. Didn't really think of that as DummyDerived could be used as Dummy, but it all makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I you change the DummyImplBase to:

```
public abstract class DummyImplBase<T> : RequiredBase<Dummy>, IDummyRequired
        where T : Dummy
{
    public void OtherMethod()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: But if I make RequiredMethod virtual and tries to override it using either T or Dummy, this solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If I make IDummyRequired generic too it works, so I guess I'll have to change some of my design to make this possible. I'm still hoping to find out why my solution doesn't work though.

```
public class Dummy
{
}

public interface IRequired<T>
{
    T RequiredMethod();
}

public interface IDummyRequired<T> : IRequired<T>
    where T : Dummy
{
    void OtherMethod();
}

public class RequiredBase<T> : IRequired<T>
{
    public T RequiredMethod()
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}

public abstract class DummyImplBase<T> : RequiredBase<T>, IDummyRequired<T>
    where T: Dummy
{
    public void OtherMethod()
    {
    }
}
```